# How to set an Alarm with React Native IOS and Android devices

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, alarm

I'm looking to make an app to set alarms/reminders and then you can manually stop/snooze.

I found some libraries for instance:
[react-native-alarm](https://github.com/smartliang/react-native-alarm) I followed the instructions of how to setting up with Android and IOS  but it failed when I tried to set an alarm, example code:

```
RNAlarm.setAlarm(
   Date.parse("2018-01-01T18:40:24Z").toString(),
   'Meeting with customer',
   '', 
   '',
   () => {
      console.log("Event triggered");
    },
   () => {
      console.log("Event trigger Failed");
 });
```

It didn't trigger the event. it looks the library is not working base in the [issues section](https://github.com/smartliang/react-native-alarm/issues/3) .
[react-native-calendar-events](https://github.com/wmcmahan/react-native-calendar-events) it didn't work as I expected since it used the calendar set reminders in the device . Does somebody know how to accomplies this in a react native application?

Comment: How did you expect them to work?  What have you tried?

Comment: @JonathanRys i just updated the question. Yes I have tried